# MongoDB monodump succeeded but can't open the archive

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, backup, mongodump, database

I have a script to backup my MongoDB. However the script was working fine until now. Every time I run the script, it'll say "done dumping...(x documents)". But when I try to access it from FileZilla, it says
`/home/ubuntu/temp/bcd.gz: open for read: no such file or directory`

`/usr/bin/mongodump -h $HOST -d $DBNAME -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase "admin" --gzip --archive=abc.gz
/usr/bin/mongodump -h $HOST -d $DBNAME2 -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase "admin" --gzip --archive=bcd.gz`

My first database always backup properly with no issue at all. The issue is always with `$DBNAME2`. The user I am using has [`backup` permission](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#backup).

Is there something wrong inside the $DBNAME2 database? If so, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there was an extra character at the end of my command in the script that windows doesn't show it. I just opened up the script on Mac and saw the extra character and removed it. Boom, got it working!